# Identifying unity gameObjects (pre-runtime) to save/load their data

Tags: unity-game-engine

I pretty much already made a little quest game for Android, and it only just occurred to me that I have to save player's progress.

I have a lot of interactive game objects (they share a script InteractiveObject that I made), which has an integer "CurrentPosition" parameter, that tracks how the player interacted with it. I need to save that parameter for all of those game objects.

What I figured I will do is pass this data to some "manager" singleton class after every interaction, and compile it into the list.. only I have nothing to identify those game objects by. GetInstanceID is unique, but not persistent, so its useless for this purpose.

Of course, I could just add "ID" parameter ty my script, and fill it by-hand in editor.. but that seems to be a suboptimal solution. There are a lot of those objects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to somehow "register" your buttons

This is basically the same idea as "give them all an ID manually" except replace manually with "using code."

The first problem you have is that all of your buttons are hand-placed in your scene and all of their interactions are done by hand and all of this was done manually with no regard to "I'm going to need to be able to identify these later" which is how you've ended up here.

## Option 1:

Have your code create, place, and name your buttons. As your code is *yours* it will just automatically generate the required ID and retrieve the state from the save file because you built it to handle this requirement from the get-go.

As you haven't already set your project up this way, this will be a lot of work spent refactoring your project to do it this way.

## Option 2:

Do it manually as you stated you don't want to do. You may have to decide that this *is* the least work-intensive solution that is also reliable.

## Option 3:

Create a class that all it does is have a `registerButton` function that shoves the buttons into an array so that they have an index `ID` value. When your buttons run their `Start()` method (if they do not have a Monobehavior script yet, give them one for this purpose) calls this `registerButton` method, which returns an ID (its literally just the button's index in the `all_the_buttons` array). Use this as your serialization ID.

Note that while this is *deterministic* (in that the buttons will register themselves in the same order every time) it occurs in an *unknown order.* If you delete, clone, create, or move the button around in the scene hierarchy, you will affect what IDs your buttons have, possibly invalidating any existing save files.

Comment: They have monobehaviors, but I thought Start()'s are not guaranteed to be called in the same order every time. I should have researched that, now I feel silly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use playerprefs to save the game data , take a look at this link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: No, I dont have trouble actually SAVING data. The question is: I have like, 50 objects in my scene named "Button", and each button, for example, has script with parameter "Position", 0 for not pressed, and 1 for pressed. The question is how do I distinguish between those buttons, if I wanted to save them in one file? As I stated above, just giving them unique identifiers by hand, like "button_1" and "button_2" etc. is plausable, but really bad decision.